# Making a form on asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a problem making a button which would actually copy the information of the form and then displaying that information right below it! Please help me out in this.
I'm doing this in ASP.NET and trying to do in web forms!
Also the IDE I'm using is visual studio 2015

Comment: We need to see more. Show us what you have so far. Right now, we don't even know if you're trying to do this in javascript or server-side, and if that latter we don't know even know what language you're using, or whether you're using web forms or mvc (or a mix).

Comment: Yes I'm sorry that I didn't mention that earlier!

Comment: I'm trying to do it in ASP.NET and I'm using the web forms in html template!

Comment: Well, that's one of the things we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in asp.net if you want server side copy the information

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="show" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label Text="result" ID="Lable1" runat="server" />
```

in behind

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lable1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: I'm actually talking about the display of the entered information in the web form below the form

Comment: just like the credentials you enter about your self in the website portal and then it displays it right underneath there!